# Connect inputs with spans

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a small input validation. The problem now is, behind every input field it says: "email can't be empty". The intention is that he picks the names of the input fields and puts these names before the messages. So you get: "userName can't be empty, password can't be empty, passwordCheck can't be empty". In this way, I want the `input fields` and `spans` to be connected to each other. Is this possible? If so, how? 
Thank you in advance.

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="span.js"></script>

    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            //validator.className = "ValidateField";
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <form>
        <div>
            Name: <input type="text" name="userName" class="ValidateField" data-validate="EmptyAllowed|min-5|max-20">
            <span class="SpanField" name="spanUser" style="color:red"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" class="ValidateField" data-validate="EmptyAllowed|min-5|max-20|symbols-not-allowed">
            <span name="spanPassword" class="SpanField" style="color:red"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            Password again: <input type="password" class="ValidateField" name="passwordCheck" data-validate="EmptyNotAllowed|min-5|max-20">
            <span name="spanPasswordCheck" class="SpanField" style="color:red"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" class="ValidateField" data-validate="EmptyNotAllowed|min-5|max-100">
            <span name="spanEmail" class="SpanField" style="color:red"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="registreren" onclick="validator.validateNow()">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript

```
var validator = (function () {
        var my = {};
        var checkList = {};
        var minList = {};
        var maxList = {};
        var validationFields;


        function validateField(field) {

            function showText(error) {
                var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("SpanField");

                for (s = 0; s < spans.length; s++) {
                    spans[s];
                }

                var say = function () {
                    spans[0].innerHTML = (field.name + error);
                    spans[1].innerHTML = (field.name + error);
                    spans[2].innerHTML = (field.name + error);
                    spans[3].innerHTML = (field.name + error);
                }
                say();
            }
            var checks = field.dataset.validate;

            checkList = checks.split('|');

            var min = checkList[1];
            minList = min.split('-');

            var max = checkList[2];
            maxList = max.split('-');

            if (EmptyNotAllowed(field.value)) {
                showText(" can't be empty");

            } else {
                alert(field.name + "OK!");
            }

            if (minLength(field.value)) {
                showText("must be longer");
            }

            if (maxLength(field.value)) {
                showText("must be shorter");
            }
        }



        function EmptyNotAllowed(value) {
            if (value == '') {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        function SymbolsNotAllowed() {
            alert("binnenkort beschikbaar");
            return true;
        }


        function minLength(value) {
            if (value.length > 0 && value.length < minList[1]) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        function maxLength(value) {
            if (value.length > maxList[1]) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        my.className = "ValidateField";

        my.validateNow = function () {

            validationFields = document.getElementsByClassName(my.className);

            for (f = 0; f < validationFields.length; f++) {
                validateField(validationFields[f]);
            }

        };

        return my;
    }());
```

Comment: for future coding. name the function by the action they are performing or the  `result` they deliver so for example rename `EmptyNotAllowed` to `isEmpty` - like this you would ask `if(isEmpty(<field>))` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the current field object that is being validated to the `showText` function and then use `field.nextElementSibling` to get the `span` and show the innerhtml your `showText()` function would look like following.

```
function showText(field,error) {
  var say = function(span) {
    span.innerHTML = (field.name + error);
  }

  //get the span
  let span=field.nextElementSibling;

  say(span);
}
```

See the demo

```js
var validator = (function() {
  var my = {};
  var checkList = {};
  var minList = {};
  var maxList = {};
  var validationFields;


  function validateField(field) {

    function showText(field, error) {
      console.log(field.nextElementSibling);

      let span = field.nextElementSibling;
      var say = function(span) {
        span.innerHTML = (field.name + error);
      }
      say(span);
    }

    var checks = field.dataset.validate;

    checkList = checks.split('|');

    var min = checkList[1];
    minList = min.split('-');

    var max = checkList[2];
    maxList = max.split('-');

    if (EmptyNotAllowed(field.value)) {
      showText(field, " can't be empty");

    } else {
      alert(field.name + "OK!");
    }

    if (minLength(field.value)) {
      showText(field, "must be longer");
    }

    if (maxLength(field.value)) {
      showText(field, "must be shorter");
    }
  }



  function EmptyNotAllowed(value) {
    if (value == '') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function SymbolsNotAllowed() {
    alert("binnenkort beschikbaar");
    return true;
  }


  function minLength(value) {
    if (value.length > 0 && value.length < minList[1]) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function maxLength(value) {
    if (value.length > maxList[1]) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  my.className = "ValidateField";

  my.validateNow = function() {

    validationFields = document.getElementsByClassName(my.className);

    for (f = 0; f < validationFields.length; f++) {
      validateField(validationFields[f]);
    }

  };

  return my;
}());
window.onload = function() {
  //validator.className = "ValidateField";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    Name: <input type="text" name="userName" class="ValidateField" data-validate="EmptyAllowed|min-5|max-20">
    <span class="SpanField" name="spanUser" style="color:red"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" class="ValidateField" data-validate="EmptyAllowed|min-5|max-20|symbols-not-allowed">
    <span name="spanPassword" class="SpanField" style="color:red"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Password again: <input type="password" class="ValidateField" name="passwordCheck" data-validate="EmptyNotAllowed|min-5|max-20">
    <span name="spanPasswordCheck" class="SpanField" style="color:red"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" class="ValidateField" data-validate="EmptyNotAllowed|min-5|max-100">
    <span name="spanEmail" class="SpanField" style="color:red"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="registreren" onclick="validator.validateNow()">
  </div>
</form>
```